# PHP datetime create from format return wrong result

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I need to check a string is match with some format, and i using `DateTime::createFromFormat` to enforce it. but it got some bugs.

example i have an date: 8/15/2020, i try to parse it to datetime object with format "d/m/Y", then i print it in to other format:

```php
   DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", '8/15/2020')->format('d-m-Y')
   // result: 08-03-2021
```

that is wreig, because i read in php.net https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
they said: d: day (1->30), m: month (1->12), Y: year (2020)

But i got an strange result? how it work? or it is the bug?

thank you for your answer.

Comment: Strange? Please do not speculate. Check with the documented behavior and explain what you obtain constitutes an exception to the rule. Also please take a look for existing material for that matter on the site.

Comment: Check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the PHP manual is not correct.

The DateTime::getLastErrors() method generates a warning if the range for the day or month is exceeded. You can evaluate this. As an an example:

```
function DateTimeCreateFromStrictFormat($format, $input){
  $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input);
  $errArr = DateTime::getLastErrors();
  return $errArr['warning_count']+$errArr['error_count'] ? false : $dt;
}
$dt = DateTimeCreateFromStrictFormat("d/m/Y", '8/15/2020');
var_dump($dt);  //bool(false)

$dt = DateTimeCreateFromStrictFormat("d/m/Y", '8/12/2020');
var_dump($dt);  //object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-12-08 10:34:34.000000" ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Your format is `day/month/year` but there is no month `15` like the `8/15/2020` being given.

Did you mean `15/8/2020`?

Comment: yes,so i want it return false to me, bacuse no month 15. but it doesn't

Comment: See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 1):

> i try to parse it to datetime object with format "d/m/Y"

... it's not clear why you tried it like that. `8/15/2020` is clearly `m/d/Y`. You need to parse it using the format it's actually written in.

You can output it again to `d/m/Y` afterwards - that is a separate operation.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", '8/15/2020')->format('d-m-Y')
```

Comment: no, actually i want to check is the string ('8/15/2020') fit with the format "d/m/Y". and i try by using DateTime::createFromFormat function. but seem it still work end return to me an  unexpected date

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question. Unfortunately you can't use createFromFormat as a validation tool in that way - it will always try to do its best and create a date from the data provided, even if it doesn't seem to make sense. To validate the format strictly you probably need to use some sort of regular expression.

Comment: _“Unfortunately you can't use createFromFormat as a validation tool in that way”_ - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php can tell you that something went wrong though.